# Is file overwriting in Java safe?

Tags: java, file, overwrite

What pattern should I follow to properly deal with the risk of software shutting off right in the middle of the serialization of some data in Java?

Let's say I have some data file that I want to update. Is it possible that all data gets lost if the application shuts off while the file is being overwritten, or does Java have a mechanism in order to prevent this from happening?

I want to make sure my files never end up in a corrupted state.

Comment: You could write to a new file, and rename it after the file has been successfully written.

Comment: I think the only way to be 100% sure is backup your file before writing a new one then delete the backup once done. On "restart" if the backup exists ask the user if they want to keep going or restore from backup.

Comment: It's what I did.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent data from being corrupted during the event of SIGINT (like ctrl+c in Linux terminal) or are u trying to handle unintentional shutdown?

Comment: Unintentional shutdown, but isn't it same consequences / different causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if Java has any mechanisms to prevent corrupted data in the event of a power outage, but you can follow steps to minimize the impact.

Let's say you have a file called `important.xml` that you want to write to. You can do this:

1. Copy `important.xml` as `important.xml.old`.
2. Write the new data to `important.xml.new`.
3. Copy `important.xml.new` to `important.xml`.
4. Delete `important.xml.old`.

This way, if the power goes out during this process, there will always be at least one copy of the old data, either in `important.xml` or in `important.xml.old`, depending on when exactly the outage occurred.

You can then add logging to determine when exactly the outage occurred, so that you can recover the data if necessary.

Comment: This is what I have done but I wanted to know if there were any built-in ways to do it in Java, just like there are Thread-safe classes.

Comment: Step 3 should be "Rename `important.xml.new` to `important.xml`." since copying might be a more elaborate operation, whereas renaming is basically just changing an identifier and less likely to be interrupted as a result. It's not necessarily an atomic operation on all file systems, but should be good enough.

Comment: I think I will write the new data to another file, and when the writting of this second file is done, the first one will be removed. When looking for the last data available, if the application finds two files it will take the oldest because it would mean there was an outage before the first file could be erased. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that all data gets lost if the application shuts off while the file is being overwritten ...

If you simply write to the file without taking any precautions, then Yes.

> I wanted to know if there were any built-in ways to do it in Java, just like there are Thread-safe classes.

1. There is no built-in way in Java.
2. This is not a thread-safety issue.  Even a thread-safe program has no guarantees that it will work correctly in the event that the JVM gets a `kill -KILL` signal, for example.

Hypothetically, this *could* be addressed in a "built-in" way if Java could assume that a typical file system provides support for transactions on file operations spanning multiple files and directories.  While examples of such file system do exist, they are not mainstream.  See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Transactional_file_systems) for more info on the topic of transactional file systems.

---

> I want to make sure my files never end up in a corrupted state.

That is not possible.

Having said that, if your application implements @ekolis's scheme correctly<sup>1</sup>, it won't see a corrupted file on restart ... unless the corruption was caused by the file system or an external agent<sup>2</sup>.  Indeed, the application may be able to detect that a update was underway and even recover the "lost" changes.  (Though you probably wouldn't want to do that automatically ... without the user's "say so".)

<sup>1 - For example, you need to do an atomic rename rather than a copy, and it may be advisable to force a file system 'sync' before the rename.

2 - No application can prevent file system corruption, or some other "external agent" messing with the file.  It relies on the OS to do this, and even a properly implemented OS cannot prevent data loss in some scenarios.</sup>

Comment: I'm fine with that, I didn't want to make sure I always have the latest updated version I know it's not possible but I wanted to find a solution to handle this case and return the previous one. Thanks for you answer I found mine!